# How do the Avengers know this fact?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Avengers were talking about Infinity Stones and they seemed to know about all 4 Infinity Stones discovered so far.

Knowing about

> Tesseract, Aether and Mind Stone was Okay.

But,

> How did they come to know about the Infinity Stone introduced in *Guardians of the Galaxy*?